# Saving a for loop output into a variable

Tags: python

For example given the following for loop:

```py
for i in range(3):
    print(i, '->',i+1)
```

Gives the output:

```
0 -> 1
1 -> 2
2 -> 3
```

How could I save this output in string form such that it is saved in a variable.

So for example could say `print(my_variable)` and the output is as the above output.

**Edit**
Given the following list:

```
[['ORGANIZATION', 'EDUCATION', 'UniversityWon', 'FormMathematics'], ['PERSON', 'Sixth', 'Economics'], ['GPE', 'FrenchUK', 'London']]
```

I have the following for loop that prints them in the desired way:

```
for i in output:
    print(i[0], '->', ', '.join(i[1:]))
```

Output of:

```
ORGANIZATION -> EDUCATION, UniversityWon, FormMathematics
PERSON -> Sixth, Economics
GPE -> FrenchUK, London
```

How can i save this output into a variable such that if i executed `print(variable)`, the above output would be printed?

Comment: Sound like an [x/y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Could you [edit] your post with some details about why you want to do this?

Comment: That would require a lot of other code which doesn't really add explanation to the problem at hand.

Comment: you may be looking for string interpolation, which is often done with an f-string or the `.format()` method

Comment: `"\n".join(f'{i} -> {i + 1}' for i in range(3))`

Answer (score 1):

A list comprehension can be used to generate the individual strings.

```
[f"{i} -> {i + 1}" for i in range(3)]
```

We can then join those with newlines.

```
"\n".join([f"{i} -> {i + 1}" for i in range(3)])
```

But we don't need to use a list comprehension here. A generator expression will be more efficient as it doesn't generate an entire list first and then iterate over that list.

```
"\n".join(f"{i} -> {i + 1}" for i in range(3))
```

If every line need to end in a newline, you can factor that into the f-string and then join them with an empty string.

```
''.join(f"{i} -> {i + 1}\n" for i in range(3))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, i have updated the question if you could take a look that would be great.

Comment: The concepts already shown can be used to accomplish that additional task.

Comment: I am not sure how to include the join within {} since this throws an error

Answer (score 0):

You can use an f-string like this:

```
result = ""

for i in range(3):
    result += f"{i} -> {i + 1}\n"

print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, i have updated the question if you could take a look that would be great.